# 'Written skills' or 'Writing skills'?

Tags: word-choice

On a CV I want to write

`Excellent writing skills`.

But for some reason `written` seems familiar.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Writing skills: skills which apply to writing. (Usually meaning composition and language skills, not mechanical handwriting/typing.)

"Written skills", if it meant anything, would mean those skills which had been written down.

Answer (score 2):

**Writing skills** or **written communication skills**.

There is also **verbal skills**.

> [verbal](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/verbal): relating to or consisting of words
>
> ▪ *The job requires someone with strong verbal skills. [=someone who is good at writing and speaking]*

Answer (score 0):

"written" is the third form of the base forms, the past or passive participle.
It is used for passive describing a passive action or for describing a state.
So "written language" is language that is written (state) or was written (action).
"a stolen" car is a car that was stolen.
Sometimes the third base form can have active sense.
"the escaped prisoner" is a prisoner who has escaped.